# how to refresh tabs data when update table?

Tags: php, mysqli

index.php

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Engineering')">Engineering</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'LAW')">LAW</button>
</div>

<div id="Engineering" class="tabcontent">
    <table class="items">
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>College Name</th>
        </tr>   
            <?php 
                $query = "select * from college where field = 'engineering'";
                $show = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) 
                {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['state']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['college_name']?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>">edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php       
                }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="Law" class="tabcontent">
    <table class="items">
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>College Name</th>
        </tr>   
            <?php 
                $query = "select * from college where field = 'law'";
                $show = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) 
                {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['state']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['college_name']?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>">edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php       
                }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

edit.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $college_name = $_POST['colleges'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $sqli = "update college set college_name = '$college_name', state = '$state' where id = '$id'";
    $results = mysqli_query($link,$sqli);
    if($result == true)
    {
        $msg .= "<p style='color:green;'>Your data update successfully</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .= "<p style='color:red;'>Errror!</p>";
    } 
}
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="<?php echo $stateid; ?>"><?php echo $statename; ?></option>
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "select * from statemaster";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<option value=".$row['stateid'].">".$row['statename']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="colleges" id="colleges">
        <option value="<?php echo $college_name; ?>"><?php echo $college_name; ?></option>
        <option value="">Select College</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" name='update' id='update'>update</button>
</form>
```

In this code when I click on edit button then it will go to edit.php page where I get id from url and  run update query after updating table college the data will update but when I move from edit page to index.php page the data will remain same but in database update data will be there. So, How can I fix this issue ?

Thank You

Comment: Where is your edit form? Is your update query work?

Comment: yes, @Fairy Dancer

Comment: come to chat ill explain clearly on it. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146504/codeigniter

Comment: It look to me that you should do use javascript to send data to edit.php and refresh/change your page on response. ajajx is the key word...

Comment: I need 20 reputation for chating @Fairy Dancer Sorry !

Comment: Ok. show your edit form page @omkara

Comment: how to refresh tabs when page load @BozidarSikanjic

Comment: sorry! guys I have some internet problem thats why I am not replying yet plsss revisit my edit.php file @Fairy Dancer

Comment: Ok now post your edit in your question so we can help you with @omkara

Comment: Ok once you submit the edit form redirect that to index.php eg. `header('Location: index.php');` So this make take you to the index.php once the data saved into database. You have to put that code inside of your if condition

Comment: Thanx mate you help me a lot @FairyDancer :)

Comment: @omkara You will send your data to edit.php. edit.php does whatever you want and returns whatever you need for updating values in your html, using javascript. Look at this and it will make more sense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for caching. It could be that the browser is not going to the server in order to get the contents of index.php, as it thinks it has it. 
Try calling index.php with a variable, like:

`<a href="index.php?<?=microtime()?>">Home</a>`

Comment: Or you can disable cache in your browser.